# What is a recommended platform that can act as a scalable image hosting for static websites?

Tags: image, hosting, image-uploading, github-pages

I've come across this issue where I don't know of any reliable places where I could upload all these images for my personal GitHub page.

I don't want to upload them directly to the GitHub repo and take up storage space.

AWS and Google Cloud seem too expensive for this small website.

Has anyone had any experience using Google Photos, Dropbox or Imgur for hosting images that get referenced on their websites?

Did that scale well?

Are there any other solutions out there I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions asking to find an off-site resource are off-topic to Stack Overflow, but I'll throw a couple ideas out there:

I'd start by just doing a Google search for "static file hosting" for a ton of results. Any of the options you mentioned will probably work, but it might be easier if you use something specifically designed to host files that are used by a website. Put another way, you could also upload all of your images to Facebook and use the URLs of the images on your site. But that's not really what it's designed for.

You could use [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which you can use to host static files. See also:

- [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)
- [How Do I Configure an S3 Bucket for Static Website Hosting?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html)
- [Moving a Static Site to S3 Before My Girlfriend Got Out of the Shower](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/static-site-s3/)

Similarly, you could use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). See also:

- [Hosting a static website with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#hosting_a_static_website_with_cloud_storage)
- [Hosting a Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)
- [Static Website Examples, Troubleshooting and Tips](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website)

I found all of the above using pretty basic Google searches, so that's where you should start. The only way to really answer this question is for you to try out a bunch of different things and see which one you like best.